# how to log stack trace aws elastic beanstalk to quickly troubleshoot customer error

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way or not asking the Google the right way. So I apologize if this is a duplicate.  I want to quickly/efficiently be able to troubleshoot client/user errors in my java webapp.

That said, we can easily see where our errors are on a local machine by doing a e.printstacktrace.  I want to know the best way to do this on an EC2/Elastic Beanstalk instance.  If a customer gets an error I want them to be able to email asking what happened on "ticket number" or "error on this date around this time".  My thought was to, when an exception happens, log the stacktrace in my DB along with the username and return the db.uniqueKey to the user so they can email me inquiring about that uniqueKey/ID number.

I don't know if this is a good idea to log substrings of a stacktrace to a db (have all those db connections open/close to log stacktraces).

When I look up this topic, I get a lot about AWS CloudWatch, but this looks more like a tool to log everything that's happening in my environment and server.. That seems like a recipe for scrolling log files forever.

Is logging a stacktrace.substring to a DB with a username a good idea? Is there a better way to get back to my users in a timely fashion on what might have happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an API call to CloudWatch Logs to send a single log message, instead of sending your entire Tomcat log files to CloudWatch. You can also send logs in [JSON format](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/01/20/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-json-log-format-support/) so that you can include metadata like your user ID, unique key, etc. See the [AWSLogsClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#putLogEvents(com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.PutLogEventsRequest)) class in the SDK.

Note that there are also third party services like [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/) and [LogEntries](https://logentries.com/) that are really good at this sort of thing, and in my opinion are much more user-friendly than CloudWatch Logs is currently. These service also provide APIs to send individual log messages from Java if you don't want to stream your entire log files to them.

I would recommend using a service designed for logging like the ones I've listed, instead of a database. These services will scale well without the need to worry about things like the number of open DB connections. These services will also handle sending alerts based on the contents of log messages, and provide a nice web interface for viewing the log messages.

If you do decide to go with a database approach I would recommend looking into [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) for this instead of a relational database like MySQL or PostgreSQL. DynamoDB will scale easily, stores documents easily as JSON data, and can trigger Lambda functions which could be used to do things like sending alerts.